Why is the Permissions-Policy: camera=() header not blocking camera access in my application?
I've been trying to restrict camera access in my web application using the Permissions-Policy header, but it's not working as expected. Specifically, I've set the header as follows:
Permissions-Policy: camera=()

Despite this, I can still access the camera through
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() 

in my application.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
function TestHeaders() {
    const [cameraAccess, setCameraAccess] = useState(null);
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

    const testCameraAccess = () => {
        // Requesting camera access
        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({ video: true })
            .then((stream) => {
                // If camera access is granted
                setCameraAccess(true);
                console.log('Camera access granted:', stream);
                stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop()); // Close camera after test
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // If camera access is denied
                setCameraAccess(false);
                setErrorMessage(error.message);
                console.error('Camera access denied:', error);
            });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Test Camera Access</h1>
            <button onClick={testCameraAccess}>Test Camera</button>
            {cameraAccess === null ? (
                <p>Click the button to test camera access</p>
            ) : cameraAccess ? (
                <p style={{ color: 'green' }}>Camera access granted</p>
            ) : (
                <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>
                    Camera access denied:
                    {errorMessage}
                </p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default TestHeaders;



I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:
Verified Header Placement: Ensured the Permissions-Policy header is correctly included in the HTTP response headers, not just in HTML meta tags.
Cleared Browser Cache: Cleared the browser cache and tested in an incognito window to ensure I'm not seeing cached responses.
Checked Browser Support: Confirmed that I am using a modern browser that supports Permissions-Policy.
Tested in Multiple Browsers: Tested the functionality in different browsers and versions.
Verified Correct Syntax: Ensured the header is correctly spelled and formatted.

Actual result:Camera() and Camera(self) both granted the access to camera
Expected : Camera()  must discard the camera access and Camera(self) must allow the same origin request.
Any insights or additional troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated!
Expected : Camera() must discard the camera access and Camera(self) must allow the same origin request.(As mentioned per as MDN documetation)
